# How do you render SVG in a different size in HTML?

Tags: svg

Given this svg:

```
<svg width="640" height="480" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
 <!-- Created with SVG-edit - http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/ -->
 <g>
  <title>Layer 1</title>
  <ellipse stroke="#000000" ry="210.999999" rx="259.000004" id="svg_1" cy="237.727263" cx="324.999989" stroke-width="5" fill="#FF0000"/>
 </g>
</svg>
```

How do I scale it to user 320x240 without having to recompute the numbers inside? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `viewBox="0 0 640 480"` and set `width="320" height="240"` to the `<svg>` element to scale the SVG. you can go crazy on the `width` and `height` and control the aspect ratio with the [`preserveApsectRatio`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute) attribute.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [viewBox](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#ViewBoxAttribute) attribute to control what you can see in the page. Alternately wrap the content in a `<g>` element and set a scale transform of 0.5 on it.